# Java regex for image filename?

Tags: java, regex

I have to filter filenames to match only image (png,jpg,gif,bmp) files, is possible to make a such regex or do I have to have different regex for every file type? It also cannot contain path like ../../ or /var/app/filename.exe etc.

Comment: From where are you getting this file paths? From browser? From FileDialog?

Comment: So you want to make validation in javascript?

Comment: No, in Java server side.

Comment: Request is made like this http://myserverurl?filename=imagefilename.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Link:

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-image-file-extension-with-regular-expression/

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: I have to mention that that code must be edited if you don't want to allow paths in filenames. I used ([\w]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$) , which means only letters and numbers are allowed in filename.

Comment: It might be useful to provide any code, with some explanation. Imagine the  blog does not exist any more.

Answer (score 12):

I'll use something like this... This should cover most cases without going too much into crazy details...

```
(.*/)*.+\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp|jpeg|PNG|JPG|GIF|BMP|JPEG)$
```

As a Java String this regex looks like this:

```
"(.*/)*.+\\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp|jpeg|PNG|JPG|GIF|BMP|JPEG)$"
```

Hope that helps... :)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy:

```
re = ".*\\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp)"
```

as long as you don't need UPPERCASE and jpeg. :)

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is working for me: `(.*/)*.+\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp|jpeg|PNG|JPG|GIF|BMP)$`